# What does the PHP notice "Undefined index" mean

Tags: php, mysql

I want to register user and login the user using PHP, MySQL and Swift, but I am getting an error.

**This is api.php**

```
<?php

include"dbconfig.php";

$request = $_POST['request'];
//$request = 'register';

if($request == 'register'){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //$email = 'shubham@gmail.com';
    //$password ='shubham';

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (:email, :password)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":email",$email);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password",$password);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $response['message'] = 'Registration Sucessfully Done..!!';
    }else{
        $response['message'] = 'Registration Faild..!!';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
else if($request == 'login'){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'");
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()==0){
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Login Field..!!';
    }else{
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'User Login Sucesssfully..!!';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}

elseif($request == 'insert'){
    $employeeID = $_POST['employeeID'];
    $employeeName = $_POST['employeeName'];
    $employeeDepartment = $_POST['employeeDepartment'];

    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO employee VALUES ( :employeeID, :employeeName,:employeeDepartment)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":employeeID",$employeeID);
    $stmt->bindParam(":employeeName",$employeeName);
    $stmt->bindParam(":employeeDepartment",$employeeDepartment);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        $response['message'] = 'New Record are Added Sucessfully ..!!';
    }else{
        $response['message'] = 'New Record Add Faild..!!';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**This is my dbconfig.php**

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "phpfile";

try{
    $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};$db_name",$db_user,$db_pass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

When I try to run this api.php file on web:

> Notice: Undefined index: request in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phpfile/api.php on line 5

I'm try to register an user with Swift code with the help of Alamofire.

Comment: Readers generally prefer succinct, clear questions, so it is best not to clutter up the post with "please halp me" pleading. This is especially true of the title - this is designed to help you describe the question accurately. Good titles will help readers find the same problem again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add new API param into POST request

```
'request' = 'register'
```

Comment: try it .... if I uncomment the //$request = 'register';   and    //$email ='shubham@gmail.com';
    //$password ='shubham';   Then also get the {"message":"Registration Faild..!!"} error on web